# How close to Kortrijk / Courtray can you get with a Lille public transport ticket (and still make it there)?

Tags: public-transport, france, belgium, lille, kortrijk

A few people have mentioned to me that the Belgian town of [Kortrijk / Courtray](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Courtray) is nice to visit as a day trip from Lille, and with a good eye can apparently (almost?) be seen from the clock tower of the Lille town hall! (It's only 15 miles)

The [WikiVoyage page for the city](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Courtray#By_train) suggests that you can get a train there pretty easily from Lille, which given the short distance one would hope was the case anyway! However, the train looks to be a whopping €8.20 one way...

Given that a [Transpole single journey ticket](http://www.transpole.fr/fr/pass-pass-et-tarifs/titres-occasionnels.aspx) is only €1.50, and given how close Kortrijk / Courtray is to the border, I'm wondering if there's a cheaper way to get there relying more on local public transport? Say, perhaps, a Lille tram or Metro most of the way, Transpole bus across the border (still on the same ticket), then a Belgian bus the last bit?

Note that I'm probably not after the closest to Kortrijk I can get on a Transpole ticket, rather the closest where there's onward public transport. Well, assuming I can't use a Transpole ticket the whole way that is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best option is to buy a "Trampoline" ticket on Lille - Kortrijk. This ticket costs 8 Euro and is valid the whole day on all trains (both ways) on the Lille - Kortrijk route.
http://telechargement.ter-sncf.com/Images/Nord_Pas_De_Calais/Tridion/flyer_trampoline_occasionnel05_tcm-26-64218.pdf
You can buy this at the ticket office, or from the ticket vending machines.

Trying to do it all using "local" transport will make the trip a lot longer, and will unlikely be cheaper than the 8 euro Trampoline ticket.

On weekends SNCF also offers Trampoline tickets to other destinations in Belgium. They're a bit more expensive, but still good deals.