# Getting from Kortrijk or Mouscron to Lille by public transport, after the last train

Tags: public-transport, france, belgium, lille, kortrijk

Following the [advice in this question on travelling from Lille to Kortrijk / Courtray and onwards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26543/26), on Saturday I headed over to Belgium. Coming back, I discovered that while there are trains quite late from elsewhere in Belgium to Kortrijk, the last train from Kortrijk or Mouscron to Lille is around 9.30pm.

If you miss the last train from Kortrijk to Lille (as I almost did due to a late running train to Kortrijk...), you can still get closer to the border to Mouscron for some time later. The last metro or the last tram from Tourcoing is quite a bit later than the last train, ditto from Roubaix (though that's further from Kortrijk or Mouscron)

Are there any ways to get a bus back from Kortrijk or Mouscron after the last train, to meet up with Lille public transport? Or is your only option the 4km walk from Mouscron to the Bourgogne metro station?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bus line especially for that (crossing the border and connecting the two networks), called MWR for Mouscron-Wattrelos-Roubaix. As you suspected it does not go to Tourcoing but to Roubaix, where you can connect to the metro and the rest of the Lille area transit network. The problem is that the [last bus service is even earlier than the last train](http://www.transpole.fr/documents/fiches_horaires/FicheHoraires-635109760704020000.pdf).

Since the line does exist but does not operate so late, I think it means the only option left is walking (or perhaps a taxi?) There is also a high-service bus to Wattrelos (called [“Liane 3”](http://www.transpole.fr/fr/reseau/reseau-soiree-2.aspx)) that runs quite late in the night. It does not go over the border but the walk from Mouscron (Herseaux station?) could be shorter (apparently a bit over 2 km on the map). I have never been there with public transport so I don't know how realistic this option is.

Comment: Looks like there's a 22:19 train from Kortrijk which arrives in Herseaux at 22:41, but it's still a 2.1km walk to the first bus stop on Liane 3 at Rue Vallon, Wattrelos. Better than the 4km walk Mouscron to Tourcoing though!